# Fourier transform with a scaled variable

Tags: calculus

Can somebody explain me the following:

Discrete Fourier transforms and their inverse are usually outlined as follows:

\begin{equation}
F(n)=\sum_{m=1}^N f(m) e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{N} mn}
\end{equation}

so if $m=N$ the the argument of the exponential is $2 \pi i n$ (periodicity).

For the inverse transform

\begin{equation}
f(m)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^M F(n) e^{\frac{2\pi i}{N} mn}
\end{equation}

I'm not sure what happens if I have to deal with a function f(x), x=[a ... b].

If I just try to find the right formula from discretizing the integral, I have

\begin{equation}
F(k)=\int_a^b f(t)e^{-2\pi i tk}dt=\sum_{m=1}^{M}f(t_m)e^{-2 \pi i t_m k }\Delta t_m=\frac{b-a}{M}\sum_{m=1}^{M}f(t_m)e^{-2\pi i t_m k }
\end{equation}

I'm not sure how to deal with $k \rightarrow k_n$. Since the $t\in [a, a+\Delta t,...a+(b-a)=b]$ I would guess $k\in [1/(b-a)...1/\Delta t]$ but the periodicity has to be fulfilled as well, and I don't see how. However, in the correct answer appears

\begin{equation}
e^{-2 \pi i t_m k_n}
\end{equation}

and the factor before the sum is OK.

Many thanks in advance.

where

\begin{equation}
k_n=\frac{M}{(b-a)^2}n=\frac{1}{\Delta t}\frac{1}{b-a}n
\end{equation}